# Unstable Results JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

In my jmeter results i see unstable results:

[image]

In this test a test with 5 users loop 2 times. In this example is the first time that the user touches the request login.aspx very slow. In all the other request i see strange differences. What can be the reason why it is sometimes slow and some times fast?

Some facts:

- Users always use every run the same data
- No hardware bottlenecks, enough space
- Tried with different cache settings but it has no effect
- I see a high latency on the slow requests, can it be a network issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here Login.aspx action will be using an SQL/Query which gets Cached after first time execution, and performing the same login action again will result in Faster result than the first time execution.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Thanks, but before this test we run a warmup with the same user that only login and logout..